# Google Chromebook 3

Tags: linux, google-chrome

Preface: 
I have looked in to the crouton download. Still not for me. I have enabled developer mode via the write protect screw on inside of laptop followed by CTRL+ALT+->[F2] but never really achieving my main goal.

My Intent:

I do not wish to "sideload" crouton next to[for sake of reason, still inside of] the google OS but instead I am wondering if there is a way that someone has found to remove the google OS *!COMPLETELY!*? Effectively to not have that in the memory at all and install my own OS, say Kali... or something of the same kind. If so, please some instruction. Everytime I peruse /usr/share/* or /usr/local/ and attempt to rewrite my information files to be susceptible to the change somehow it seems it either doesn't work or I hit a snag and put the device to sleep only to return to it being returned to the factory default. Thx

Answer (score 0):

you could probably load 'linux puppy' os from a usb external cd rom and then wipe the partition, using linux puppy to install a copy of linux and grub (or grub2) and then chain up from there.

this is assuming that the boot partition isnt write protected.

Comment: word! I'll give it a shot and let you know what happens. . . Thx again